# Cooperative Crafting and Amazing Tools of Manufacture

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting

I have a crafting based character with the [Valet Familiar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar/familiar-archetypes/valet-familiar-archetype/) archetype meaning I always craft with a [cooperative crafting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/cooperative-crafting) buddy.

A friend who also has a crafting character has started using [Amazing Tools of Manufacture](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/tools-amazing-tools-of-manufacture/).

So my question is, by RAW how would these two things interact under the two following circumstances.

1. Crafting a potion worth 4k, would the tools and cooperative crafting stack making this only take a single hour? If so would the tools be used up for the day or would it count as at the 2k limit but not over it?
2. Crafting an item worth 20k, how much progress could be made in a single day? I've been assuming 5.5k as if you break down the hours you normally make 500 gold progress an hour, assuming you bump the DC by 5 so you craft in 4 hours instead of 8. So if one hour becomes 2k then it would be 2k+(500*7)=5500. Is this correct? Can the tools be used by one person in the first hour and then another on the second?

Answers would preferably sit in the RAW as my GM tries to stick to that as best we can and only nerfs things if they are breaking the game.

Answer (score 2):

### They do not interact at all.

> The wielder may use the tools to **create items using the Craft skill** much more surely and quickly.

The tools are used to make **mundane** masterwork-quality items. While when creating magic items, the mundane object should be present before you start the process.

It then follows to explain the differences and bonuses granted by the item:

> The wielder may take **raw materials with a value equal to half the price of an object** to be crafted, and produce a finished object in as little as **1 hour for an item with a final cost of 2,000 gp or less**. For objects with a final cost of more than 2,000 gp, the wielder can perform 2,000 gp worth of work in a single hour, but only once each day. Only **a single skill check is required to successfully complete the item**, made on the last day of crafting and gaining the +4 circumstance bonus granted by the tools.

- The requirement of 30% of the item's cost as raw materials is replaced by 50% of the item's cost.
- The time spent on the process is *much* shorter, hours instead of weeks.
- You only make a single skill check instead of several skills checks per process period.

Although the [Magic Item Creation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation) rules say that you can use another skill other than Spellcraft, the method of crafting being used is not the [Craft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft) skill.

> At the end of this process, the spellcaster must make a single skill check (usually Spellcraft, but sometimes another skill) to finish the item. If an item type has multiple possible skills, you choose which skill to make the check with.

That means that if you do everything by yourself, the process is much shorter, as creating masterwork quality items usually take much longer than enchanting with magic.

For instance, crafting a masterwork (+150 gp) full plate armor (1,500 gp) should take **over 10 months** for a single character with about +10 on his craft skill, as seen on  [this calculator](http://viajon.net/pf/crafting/). The tools make this possible in less than a day.

You do receive the tool bonuses for using the Craft skill to create magical items though. That is the point of being able to use a different skill other than Spellcraft.

Comment: The tools can be used for magic items as the rules for magic items state you can use a craft skill as the final roll to complete the item. If that wasn't the case then you would be correct. Nowhere in the item says it cannot be used for magic items or only on mundane.

Comment: The rules say you can replace the skill being used, not the methods. If the method was replaced, you would follow the Craft skill rules instead. But it clearly says *"The wielder may use the tools to create items using the Craft skill much more surely and quickly."*. It then follows to state the differences on this method (50% materials instead of 30% and so on).

Comment: As written, I think that @ShadowKras is right, but http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/master-craftsman-final/ would allow a character to sidestep the RAW aspect of the Tools not being terribly useful in crafting magic items (which, given their price and description, I think wasn't exactly RAI).

Comment: @minnmass you are correct that you can use the craft skill to make magic items, but note that you are using the magic item creation rules when doing so, not the craft skill rules. Which is the distinction i want to make clear.